# Are go modules meant to be installed as executable programs or packages?

Tags: go, go-modules

Can Go modules be built as an executable program? Or, are they meant to be published as libraries for code reuse?

Comment: Both. Go modules can, an often do, contain `main`, which is how executables are defined in Go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building an executable and publishing a library are not mutually exclusive (note that modules are not compiled, *packages* are).

> A module is a collection of related Go packages that are versioned together as a single unit.
>
> Modules record precise dependency requirements and create reproducible builds.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#modules

Whether these packages contain a main package or not is irrelevant.

Comment: `main` is special from other packages though. Package `A` can depend on package `B`. However, `main` can never be `B`. `main` is always at the root of the dependency tree.

Answer (score 4):

They're intended to work as packages, like something you would install from NPM for a JavaScript project, or from PIP in a Python project.